# toggle Ionic React Radio button in a List

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, arraylist, mapping

Below is the map that I created. It lists out the equipment needed before a user can accept the job offer.

**CheckBox Function**

```
 function handleCheckbox(e, item) {
    const checkedBoxes = [...checkedBoxes];
    if(e.target.checked) {
      checkedBoxes.push(item)
    } else {
      const index = checkedBoxes.findIndex((ch) => ch === item);
      checkedBoxes.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setCheckedBoxes(checkedBoxes);
  }
```

**Map List**

```
{Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => {
         return (

       <IonItem key={item}>
        <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
        <IonRadio mode="md" slot="start" value={item} checked={checkedBoxes.find((ch) => ch !== item)} onIonChange={(e) =>{handleCheckbox(e, item);}}/>
       </IonItem>


         );
       })}
```

I have an "accept" button that needs to be disabled until all the radios are checked.

I'm having an issue with once the radio is checked, it can not be unchecked, and also I'm not sure how to validated if it is checked or not, because they could all be different depending on the job that's offered.

Normally I take a fields input Id and pass that to a function to make sure it is not empty.

**Example Validation Function**

```
\\\\\\\validate Input's\\\\\\\\\\\

function validateForm() {
    return ( streetAddress.length > 0 && city.length > 0 && state.length > 0);
}
```

**Button Validation**

```
\\\\\\\\\button is disabled unless {!validateForm} returns true.\\\\\\\

 <IonButton disabled={!validateForm()} onClick={checkPrice} expand="block" type="button" >Calculate</IonButton>
```

How do I get the checked item to uncheck, and how do I validate if they are checked or not?

Comment: Still trying to figure this out! Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!